# How to list in order of the point

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to list users in order of points. But I didn't migrate point column, I define the point in the model like below.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  def my_point(user)
    point = user.posts.count * 10 + user.followers.count * 2
  end
end
```

How can I arrange users in the view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that you can reference `self` to reference the instance, removing the argument from your method.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  def points
    (self.posts.count * 10) + (self.followers.count * 2)
  end
end

@users = User.includes(:posts, :followers).all.sort_by { |user| user.points }
```